# Emulate Splunk `fit` command with a `by` clause

Tags: machine-learning, splunk

Consider this query:

```
| makeresults count=100000
| eval a=if(random()%2==0,"apple", "banana")
| eval b=if(random()%2==0,"cherry","date")
| eval c=if(random()%2==0,"eggplant",if(random()%2==0,"fig",if(random()%2==0,"grape","huckleberry")))
| eval x=random()
| eval y=random()%x
```

What I'd like is to simply add:

```
| fit y from x by a, b, c
```

Then, I would get a total of `n` models (16 in this case) created and applied to the data, which I can then do stuff with.

Unfortunately, Splunk's `fit` command does not support a `by` clause.

The question is, how can I use the commands that ARE available to accomplish the same thing?

I've tried using `map` but that is limited to 10 subqueries.

I've tried using `foreach` but that complains: "Search pipeline may not contain non-streaming commands"

Are there commands available to me that will let me do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The `map` command is not limited to 10 searches - that's just the default.  You can specify more searches with the `maxsearches` option.  `| map maxsearches=100 "fit y from x"`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  But that may be because I hit my resource quota.  Indeed, when I tried it with a test query, it worked great.